EnvDTE Framework informations programmatically

Is there any way to programmatically get the info which Framework is selected ?
I already looked it up in the ENVDTE wiki of MS but no info also i tryed to get the info by the "OutputPath" of the Current ConfigManager but no luck so far it's per default every time the first one.

also found out the Menu is called Framework but ther the traces end.
I need to know what Framework the user want to Debug so i can prepare things in the background.

This can be done via the GetProjectFrameworksAsync from public interface IActiveDebugFrameworkServices from Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Managed.
The main issue is that Microsoft doesn't publish it to nuget, so you need to add the vs-impl feed to your Nuget sources.
